# How to fill the inner gaps of each part and segment to different parts

Tags: image-segmentation

I wanted to fill the inner gaps and segment these three points either in Matlab and Opencv. I couldn't use morphology methods because like erosion because it makes inner gaps larger. Actually I was thinking of geometry methods but I didn't have any idea about how to discriminate inner and boundary gaps.

[image]

My output image should be something like this.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is the above image the input image? It looks like some segmentation algorithm was already applied ...

Answer (score 0):

I get [this result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/WatershedResult_cxBq2.png) when doing the following stets:

- Opening to clean the patterns contours
- Binarization
- Ultimate eroded (UE) in order to have the centers of each pattern.
- Dilation in order to merge the UE results that are too close
- Connected component labeling of the previous dilation. The labels are going to be the inner markers.
- Corners are the outer markers
- Gradient of the binary image (step 2 result).
- Watershed